# handle alert from the system doesn't always display, selenium web driver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDXve.png)I have an alert displayed when logged to system if the user already have logged before, so this alert doesn't display when the user didn't logged before. But some time is logged and I want to handle the alert in both cases.

this is the html for alert:

```
<tr>
<td>
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hidKeepLogin" type="hidden" 
name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidKeepLogin"/>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMessage" class="MessageLabelStar"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way:

```
try {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {}
```

or you somehow find out the user is logged in or not:

```
    Boolean userLogged = null; // specify condition to get true or false

    if (userLogged == true) {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    }
    else {

    }
```

Comment: post an image of the alert pls

Comment: I have added more details hopefully it will be more clear, the alert displayed only if the user logged so sometimes it will not be displayed, I don't know how to handle the two cases in the same time

Comment: So if the alert appears you want to force logout the logged user? This can be achieved by deleting some cookie. Right? In that case you shouldn't see the alert ever again.

Comment: yes I want the force logout to happen, and this alert will not be displayed if the user logout using the logout button in the system, but if the user close the browser for example without logout, then tried to login in other time it will display again

Comment: what i mean that i can't expect if the alert will display or not so i need a function to handle these two cases

Comment: 1. delete cookies
2. login
3. check cookies, find the one the keeps the login session, should have an unique name
4. in code delete the session cookie before unexpected alert can be displayed.
That's it. See https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: Destroy the session any other way. As I see it, point is to avoid the alert.